# Car wants to die and bog out after driving short distance

Tags: toyota, fuel-system, camry, stall, pump

2000 Camry LE 2.4L When driving, approximately 5-8 miles or so, car wants to die and bog out. I try to pump the gas pedal and ends up sputtering and dying. Could it be the fuel pump?  Replaced fuel filter already.